# Share Core Data between iOS and WatchOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, watchos

I have an app which uses core data and i'm trying to add a WatchOS version.
I'm already using App Groups with this method `containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier`, but how to share a PersistentStore using Core Data in objective-c?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you already doing with `containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier`? That's the method you use to find the right directory. Is it not working? What problem are you having with it?

Comment: @TomHarrington I don't understand how to use persistentStore with both devices using core data. I know that containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier need to find the directory

Comment: I have the same problem ... Did you find any solution for that.?

Comment: https://github.com/irekasoft/TimeTracker---CoreData-Demo-

Answer (score 2):

Fillipo you can't share persistent storage between apple watch extension & iPhone application. Apple doesn't allow it. Even there us no way to share Userdefaults also. Initially applw allow us to share the Userdefaults but now this functionality is removed. You need to maintain two seprate copy of databases & sync the databases with iWatch connectivity.